# BASH: find directory and count number of results using wc -l

Tags: bash

I have 3 directories 2 of which that can't be read;

```
d-----S--- 2 me me 4096 Feb 10 11:02 dir1
d-----S--- 2 me me 4096 Feb 10 11:02 dir2
drwxrws--- 2 me me 4096 Feb 10 11:02 dir3
```

My find command is : find . -type d  1>/dev/null

```
find: `./dir1': Permission denied
find: `./dir2': Permission denied
```

I basically want to find the number of directories I can't read and count them. 
How do I count this now? so far I have tried the following;

```
find . -type d 1> /dev/null | cat | wc -l

find . -type d  -print 1>/dev/null | tee /dev/tty | wc -l
```

They all return 0. Why is that? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `find` you can use `! -readable` to get all non-readable entries:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -readable -printf '.' | wc -c
```

Using `-printf '.' | wc -c` to get the counting right when a directory name consists of newlines.

Comment: thank you. +1 for readable. Can you explain what "-printf '.\n' " do?

Comment: `-printf '.\n'` prints a `DOT` for each directory found. This is to avoid get the counting right when when a directory name consists of newlines

Answer (score 2):

Permission Denied goes to the standard error so I'd try something like this:

```
$ find <your_path_here> -type d 2>&1 | grep -c "Permission denied"
```

And... if you really want to use `wc -l`:

```
$ find /proc -type d 2>&1 | grep "Permission denied" | wc -l
```

Comment: So the second one seems to work. Thank you. Now how can I do this without grep?

Comment: You can try this `find <your_path> -type d 2>&1 1>/dev/null | wc -l` to pipe stderr to wc -l and get rid of stdout. But this will count all error messages and not just "Permission Denied".